# Domain login effecting didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge in ios App

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I am working on an app that needs to download a web page from our iis based website. If I am logged into the domain for my wireless connection on my iPad the site I am connecting to seems to use that login for my credentials. However, if I am not connected to the domain or I am connected as a user who does not have access to the page it does fire the `didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge`, otherwise it does not. If I use Safari to connect to the same page it asks for authentication regardless. I am hoping to get the app to authenticate each time. Any help would be appreciated.

Code to request page :

```
NSError *error = nil;
// assign the cmh url from user prefs
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:cmhUrl];

// Put that URL into an NSURLRequest
NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[req setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];

// Create a connection that will exchange this request for data from the URL
connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req
                                             delegate:self
                                     startImmediately:YES];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like when you authenticate in Safari the auth-token is saved in NSHTTPCookieStorage. And when you making request from the code, all cookies from the storage are added to the header, so there is no need to ask for a token again.
Try to clear the storage before you making the request:

```
NSHTTPCookieStorage *cookieStorage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
for (NSHTTPCookie *cookie in cookieStorage.cookies) {
    [cookieStorage deleteCookie:cookie];
}
```

Hope this helps.